# What is the difference between $O(n + \log n)$ and $O(n + n/2)$?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, recursive-algorithms

I've learned that when we see O(log n) we consider that a given problem is halve every time. So having O(n + log n) would be that we first iterate n times once and then the problem is continually halved until resolution.

Does O(n + n/2) = O(3/2 n) mean the same thing except that the problem is halved once after iterating n times once aswell?

Comment: $O(n+\log n)$ is the same class of functions as $O\left(\frac32n\right)$, which is the same as $O(n)$.

Comment: In general, $g\in O(f)$ (as $x\to\infty$) means that there are some $\alpha>0$ and some $M$ such that $\lvert g(x)\rvert \le \alpha\lvert f(x)\rvert$ for all $x\ge M$.

Comment: @WindBreeze it might be useful for you to read at least the example and properites sections  of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: So if someone asks you to write an algorithm that runs in O(3/2 n) is he essentially asking the same as if he would require the algo to run in O(n + log n). I know that both of them are going to be in O(n) but I want to know if they're different or not.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it should. I advise you to check the request with the person of interest, because using $O\left(\frac32 n\right)$ to denote $O(n)$ is unnecessarily convoluted. This may or may not indicate that in that person's mind the notation is supposed to mean something else.

Comment: To give context, my teacher wrote an algo that would have O(n + log n) runtime and then while laughing said : "What if at the exam we told you to write the same algo but in 0(3/2 n)? think about it."

Comment: Right, sounds like they were making a joke because the point is that they are all $O(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Using your mental model, $O(\log(n))$ does not mean that "the problem is halved every time", that would rather correspond to $O(n+n/2+n/4+n/8\cdots)=O(2n)$.

---

Technically, $O(n+\log(n))$ and $O(n+n/2)$ are both equivalent to $O(n)$, they make no difference. In fact, you cannot decompose the processing precisely in distinct phases by just looking at the asymptotic complexity. The Big-O notation is just a global result.

---

Possible interpretations:

- $O(\log(n))$: the problem *size* (i.e. the number of elements) is halved iteratively, but only a constant number of elements is processed every time.
- $O(\sqrt n)$: the elements are arranged in a square, and a single row of the square is processed.
- $O(n)$: every element is processed a constant number of times. Alternatively, the data set is processed in successive $O(n)$ passes, and gets halved on every pass.
- $O(n\log(n))$: the data set is processed in successive passes while the number of elements remains unchanged. The number of passes is determined by repeatedly halving the size, though all elements are kept.
- $O(n^2)$: every pair of elements is processed.